# Detect color in image

Tags: r, image, image-processing, colors

I would like to have R detect a given color in a section of an image.

I've been reading about RGB schemes, but I thought there would maybe a package or a way to have R detect a cluster of pixels where, for example, the color yellow takes place.

Is there a solution or am I just trapped in RGB?

Thanks.

Comment: how is your image stored? is it perhaps a binary file, or a csv, of rbg values?

Comment: you are never trapped in RGB. asking for packages or libraries is considered off-topic here. I suggest you search the web for "colour segmentation in R"

Comment: @cptwonton, I have no idea. Is there a way to check? Pardon for the lack of knowledge.

Comment: So, a follow up to @cptwonton, what do you mean by color? In RGB color space, if you are dealing with an 8 bit 3 band raster, where each band has values that can occupy a range of 0-255. 'Yellow' here, is what you define it, but would be delineated by something in the order ~(255,255,0). Is it that you are interested in  capturing a range of pixels or specific pixel values?

Comment: @MigueldeDeus check this link http://ciphervision.com/Color-based-object-detection

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you go:

```
install.packages('raster')
library(raster)
#Get some data
duck.jpg<-tempfile()
download.file('http://www.pilgrimshospices.org/wp-content/uploads/Pilgrims-Hospice-Duck.jpg',duck.jpg,mode="wb")

#Plug it into a stack object
duck.raster<-stack(duck.jpg)
names(duck.raster)<-c('r','g','b')
#Look at it
plotRGB(duck.raster)

duck.yellow<-duck.raster

duck.yellow$Yellow_spots<-0
duck.yellow$Yellow_spots[duck.yellow$r<250&duck.yellow$g<250&duck.yellow$b>5]<-1
plot(duck.yellow$Yellow_spots)
```

So, just a few teachable points here. A digital image is basically a bucket for holding pixel values. So all you need to do to subset a raster (read: digital image), is use some tool to read it into R; decide how you want to subset it; and subset it in the same way you would subset any other data in R.
Another way to think about a raster in R is a stack of same size matrices, with the number of matrices in the stack as the number of bands in the image. In this manner, you can manipulate the data as you would manipulate any other matrix in R.