# Using R to extract a specific colour from an image

Tags: r, image, colors, rgb, raster

I'm new to both Stackoverflow and coding in general, but I hope I can find some answers here.

For an assignment in computational art history, I want to find a way in RStudio that can **display a specific colour in an image, leaving the rest in greyscale**.
[Like how this photo looks, only detecting the blue from the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOGwY.jpg)

What I want to end up achieving is uploading an image of a painting, and showing that a specific type of blue (rgb(65,102,245) or 'ultramarine') was used by Johannes Vermeer and locating it on his *Girl with the Pearl Earring*. I can do it with .tif or any other format.

I've tried RGB rasters like described [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2016/01/color-quantization-in-r/) but I ended up getting errors when I tried to perform it with my own photo (like "alpha level NA, not in [0,1]"). Perhaps I can try that again and show where I go wrong - but to be frank any help/support is welcome at this point!

Best, Doris

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647885/detect-color-in-image

Comment: No I hadn't, but thank you so much!! It has helped me locate the blue - that's great. Do you happen to know if I can look for a specific type of blue (#4166f5) in there?